# Best way to load and cache all the containers in unity from the configuration file

Tags: .net, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a Unity.config file wherein i will have several containers and that each container will have a list of type mapping details.

Is there a best way for me to read them at a stroke and then load & cache them for later use for better performance.

Also, let me know the performance improvement steps for the unity containers addition and type resolution with Unity containers.

Comment: Each application (appdomain) should typically have a single container instance. Why do you think you need multiple containers in your case?

Comment: @Steven: I need to have containers for specific users so that they resolve their classes via their own containers

Comment: @Steven: I have grouped the services [classes], so only they have to reside in different containers

Comment: What type of application are you running? ASP.NET?

Comment: @Steven: I am using asp.net mvc2 app with services and data layers configured via unity. i am using enterprise library version 4.

Comment: What services need to be registered per user? Where do you store your containers? In the session? How many users does your application have?

Comment: @Steven: i have user service, access services etc. I store the containers in a static object. my application will have around 5-100users

Comment: There are a lot of problems with having multiple containers, such as increased memory footprint, lower performance, and a hard to maintain [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). I'm not convinced that having a container per user is helping you. Here's a tip: Post a new question on Stackoverflow about having multiple containers. Show some code to explain why you think you need multiple containers and ask if you are doing the right thing. Also explain your type of application and how you store those containers (showing code helps a lot).